# A step in making disjoint cyclic decomposition of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Let $\pi$ be a permutation on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

We want to show that $\pi$ is product of disjoint cycles (I am not considering uniqueness now).

Start with $1$, and consider $1,\pi(1),\pi^2(1),\ldots, \pi^n(1)$.

By Pigeonhole, two of them are equal. Now, following Zassenhaus' Theory of Groups, he writes:

> Let $\pi^i(1)=\pi^k(1)$ with $i>k\ge 0$ be the first equation of this sort.

**Question:** How can we state this in more precise way that we always get **first equation** of this type?

To make clear my doubt, suppose we are presenting it in a class, where students have not seen proof of it, and suppose student put following equations
$$
\pi^2(1)=\pi^{8}(1) \hskip5mm \mbox{ and } \pi^3(1)=\pi^5(1).
$$
How do we decide which one is first equation according to Zassenhaus? Is it according to smallest-ness of one index? Or is it w.r.t. difference in $i$ and $k$? Or is it w.r.t. sum $i+k$?

I got stuck with these questions raised myself, but didn't find answer. In short, I want to write the quoted statement of Zassenhaus in more clear way. How to proceed?

---

- **Note:** It can be shown that $\pi(1), \pi^2(1), \ldots, $ are not all distinct; and one can deduce that

> *there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $\pi^m(1)=1$.*

Then using Well-ordering principle, one can take $m$ to be least.
But, I am trying to follow arguments of Zassenhaus, since it doesn't need well-ordering principle.

Comment: The smallest $i$. In other words, go through the sequence $1=\pi^0(1),\pi^1(1),\pi^2(1),\ldots, \pi^n(1)$ and stop at the first time you find a duplicate, a $\pi^i(1)$ that is equal to some earlier $\pi^k(1)$ (where earlier means $k<i$).